# How to pass a ul element to already existing html input value?

Tags: html, html-lists

How to pass a 'ul' to html input value as shown below?

```
 <input value="<ul><li>Testing</ul></li><ul><li>Testing1</ul></li>"/>
```

It is displayed as a pure string now as shown below

```
  <ul><li>Testing</ul></li><ul><li>Testing1</ul></li>
```

I need to display it as :

- Testing

- Testing1

Comment: Are you sure this ul html has the correct markup?

Comment: You need to display html markup inside input textbox? **You can't**. You can only put raw values inside form elements. Go get some plugins which could do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first this is how your ul should be :

- item1
- item2

add the container to receive the content

```
<div id=container></div>
```

add an id to your input

```
<input id="input" value="<ul><li>Testing</ul></li><ul><li>Testing1</ul></li>"/>
```

and then use jquery for the rest

```
$("#container").append($("#input").val());
```

Comment: Cant do this as I can't touch the already existing html for my small requirement. Any other feasible way to do this by having minimal changes in the target html? I am passing the value to html from java. Can I do anything while passing this String?

Answer (score 0):

If you need two items, use an unordered list and have each list item contain an input field.

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace your `input` with a `contenteditable` element, then you might be able to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <ul>
        <li>Testing</li>
        <li>Testing1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/225/

**As a note, please check the ul mark-up, I doubt whether the mentioned markup is correct.**